# how can i set sitename from IIS in to my log4net created file

Tags: .net, iis, log4net

I am using log4net in my .NET projects and logs are being created with names like:

`C:\\Inetpub\\zz_appLogs\\<hard coded sitename>\\<yyyyMMdd>\\<hard coded file name with txt extension>`

Now I want to change the log file name with current site name in IIS. I have tried this in log4net settings but it didnt work:

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" 
      value="C:\Inetpub\zz_appLogs\MYsiteLogs\" />
...
<datePattern 
      value="yyyyMMdd\\&quot;%property{CURRENTSITENAME}_info.txt&quot;" />
```

The resultant logs are having filename as follows:

```
C:\Inetpub\zz_ErrorLogs\MVCdoctoolLogs\20100304\  
      %property{CURRENTSITENAME}_error.txt`
```

I am setting the property in app_start in Global.ascx file of project:

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["CURRENTSITENAME"] = 
        System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.SiteName;
```

Can you tell me how I can set the sitename from IIS in the resultant txt file created by log4net.

thanks in advance 
 :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried myself and the following gave me the expected result. I did test with a console application, but I do not see how this should change anything:

```
  <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="c:\temp\%date{yyyyMMdd}\%property{SiteName}.txt" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="1" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%date [%2thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
  </appender>
```

Comment: hi,
i am using this :
file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\Inetpub\zz_appLogs\MVCdoctoolLogs\%date{yyyyMMdd}\%property{CURRENTSITENAME}.txt"

But the log file are now creating at this path :
C:\Inetpub\zz_appLogs\MysitaName\20100304\MYTESTSITENAME.txt.2010-03-04

i have not specified "datePattern" in appender.But it is appening the date in filename at end.

Now , i can read the property for sitename & date too.Buy how about the date at end of filename...